# UICollectionView change orientation incorrect number of cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView that displays 2 columns when in portrait mode, then when the iPhone is rotated to landscape, it displays 4. However, when the device is rotated back to portrait mode, it attempts to display 3 columns. So it display 2 columns properly and only about a quarter of the third column as it doesn't fit. Has anybody experienced this, and how did you fix it? I would have thought it should work it out automatically.

Thanks

Comment: Chang flow layout sizeItem or resize collectionView.frame in willRotate

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my problem by disabling autolayout on my UICollectionViewCell. It turns out that I didn't need autolayout for my cell as the layout is fixed and doesn't change depending on device or orientation.